# Is there an algorithm for algorithms time/space complexity optimisation?

Tags: algorithms, turing-machines, time-complexity, optimization, space-complexity

In 1950s a number of methods for [circuit minimization for Boolean functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_minimization_for_Boolean_functions) have been invented. Is there an extension of those methods or anything similar for optimising time or space complexity of algorithms?

For example an implementation of [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) as an input for such an algorithm would produce an implementation of a sorting algorithm with time complexity closer to $O(n\log n)$.

Comment: Go away!! We CS profs make a living from teaching sophisticated algorithms, your suggestion would leave us without a job!

Comment: Well... what do you expect from AI then?

Comment: Bubble sort isn't a Boolean function. Worse, not all sorting algorithms are equivalent! For example, some are not stable.

Comment: You are quite right but bubble sort and "good sort" is just an example of what I see as input and output, let's not concentrate on details.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus surely returning a sorted array isn't easier than returning true or false

Comment: @vonbrand My point was that what bubble sort does isn't quite "returning a sorted array". It's a bit more complicated than that.

Answer (score 11):

Look up [Blum's speedup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum's_speedup_theorem) (yes, this article is less than informative; look at a book on complexity theory). It essentially says that there are programs for which there is a program doing the same job that is faster by any specified margin for almost all input data.

By [Rice's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice's_theorem), it is impossible to know if two given programs do the same job.

Yes, for some *very restricted* notions of "program", given an example one can construct the "best possible" program for the job. Important classes, even. But a very far cry from anything which is able to express bubblesort.